How to disable Visual Studio Code current tag preview
How can I disable parent brackets showing while I scroll through the editor? It's sticky at the top and showing what tags I am currently in.
As you can see in the image, I am at the row 38 but rows 2,27,34 are sticky at the top because those are the rows that parent tags are in.
I don't want to see that.
It may be because of some plugin I have, but I am not really sure. How can I disable this feature?


You can disable it by turning off sticky scroll in settings.
It can be found under "Text Editor" in the ui.

Or changed using the editor.stickyScroll.enabled property in settings.json.
Global:
// settings.json
{
  "editor.stickyScroll.enabled": false
}

Only for html
// settings.json
{
  "[html]": {
    "editor.stickyScroll.enabled": false
  }
}

